# Python MatPlotLib Boxplot Colors

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to make a boxplot using the matplotlib package in Python.

```py
distinctsets.boxplot(column = 'list_price', by = 'review_difficulty', patch_artist = True, vert = False, showfliers = False, boxprops = dict(facecolor = 'lightblue'))
plt.xlabel('List Price of Individual Lego Sets')
plt.ylabel('Assembly Difficulty Reviews')
plt.title('Prices of Lego Sets by Review Difficulty')
plt.suptitle('')
```

[image: Lego Boxplot]

Currently, all of the boxes are lightblue because that it what I set the facecolor to.
How can I change this code so that each box is a different color (eg. 'Very Easy' = red, 'Easy' = Green, etc.)?

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/statistics/boxplot_color.html